# Flutter app behind corporate firewall throws TLS error during packages get

Tags: proxy, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Recently have installed Flutter and exploring hello-world app. Followed all steps mentioned at https://flutter.io/get-started/ and was able to run

**:: flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.0)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
! Doctor found issues in 1 categories.
```

Also was able to create app skeleton with following command;

**:: flutter create myapp**

But when it was trying to install all dependencies mentioned under pubspec.yaml, it started showing error and kept trying to reconnect again. Here is the logs,

```
Running "flutter packages get" in hello_world...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
```

I suspect its because of firewall and for other package managers I have been using proxy server to enable fetch which works just fine. I could not find a way to implement such proxy for flutter or pub. I also tried to use china server but that also didn't helped me. I have installed and uninstalled couple of time to make sure cache is not causing this issue.

Does anyone have figured this out yet?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I am working in a company and I had to use https_proxy env variable to get connection.

Open cmd on Windows

> set https_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port
>
> flutter create
>
> flutter run
>
> flutter packages get

This worked for me, hope it helps!

Comment: please tell me values of username, pass etc, or if its confidential please tell me how can i get this?

Answer (score 4):

I was successful after setting the following windows environment variable.

Variable name: DART_VM_OPTIONS
Variable value: --root-certs-file=path_to_cert

Where path_to_cert is the fully qualified path.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to setup a self-signed certificate to make it work correctly by setting the following enviroment variables:

On Linux:

> export DART_VM_OPTIONS="--root-certs-file={path.to.certificate.file}"

On Windows:

> set https_proxy="--root-certs-file={path.to.certificate.file}"

Comment: I've tried using the self-signed path as you describe.  I don't think pub respects this though as it claims I am using an invalid port.  Invalid proxy configuration PROXY "--root-certs-file=C:\users\jonatmo\documents\XXX-ProxyICA_B64.cer", invalid port '\users\jonatmo\documents\XXX-ProxyICA_B64.cer"

Comment: @Montwell did you find a solution?

Comment: @kushal.8 I did, see my answer.

Comment: @kushal.8 This is a windows environment variable.  You'll have to find the equivalent for macOS

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try this

Comment: where will you get the .cer file?

Answer (score 1):

Do this for windows environment

```
set https_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port
set http_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port
set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

before calling
flutter create <flutter_project>

Answer (score 0):

TLS error means : there is time zone difference, means you are in India and you have set the US time zone. The server understands that someone has intercepted the connection or connection is somehow manipulated, hence the error.

So make sure your country of origin and time zone are same. Check in windows setting--> Time and Language and you will get drop down there choose time zone of your country and RESTART the PC and now run flutter doctor you will see below message.

```
> Checking Dart SDK version... 
> Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine...
> Expanding downloaded archive... 
> Building flutter tool... 
> Running pub upgrade...
```

i tried many things for this error, but ultimately applied First Principle approach and got the solution.

Best of luck.