# Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: dart, flutter, tls1.2, dart-pub

I am getting below error-

```
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub upgrade failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
```

My understanding is I am on office network(VPN) thats why I am getting this error. I have tried multiple options and I have seen multiple multiple post but no post shows the exact way of doing things. So I will post my all questions here, if anyone help it will be really helpful for all persons who are going to start work on flutter

1) How to set and create a self-signed certificate?
Do we need to create a self signed certificate for `pub.dartlang.org` domain?
 have tried to create a certificate by using this (https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) use domain as `pub.dartlang.org`, is this a correct way or how to do it?
2)I have put `DART_VM_OPTIONS=--root-certs-file=C:\Users\dev\certs\chrome.cer` as my certificate but still issue not resolved.
3)If I have to set `https_proxy`? What are the values for hostname and port in VPN? How can i find these values?
[Flutter app behind corporate firewall throws TLS error during packages get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883151/flutter-app-behind-corporate-firewall-throws-tls-error-during-packages-get)
4) To solve this issue I have seen the reference of this comment
https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1882#issuecomment-415588527
How to implement this?

I have tried multiple things, if anyone can help how to bypass this error that will help many persons, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I have same error on MACbook when running Flutter Create. When I opened the web-browser to access pub.dartlang.org, there is an error message that says:  Your Clock is set incorrectly.

Somehow my date was set to a week ago. Fixing the date resolve the TLS issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a network error or some kind of permission issue. I was facing same issue. In my case it was due to network permissions in our organisation. I tried with some another network which has full access and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem with restricted network.
You can set **proxy**

```
systemProp.http.proxyPort=PortNumber
systemProp.https.proxyPort=PortNumber
systemProp.http.proxyUser=User
systemProp.https.proxyUser=User 
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=Password
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=Password
systemProp.https.proxyHost=YourHost
systemProp.http.proxyHost=YourHost
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=YourNonHost
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=YourNonHost
```

Comment: please tell me values of username, pass etc, or if its confidential please tell me how can i get this ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the restricted environment variables sequence. You can set bash_profile：

```
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn
```

keynote：

```
"FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL" is in front of "PUB_HOSTED_URL"
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also getting the same error, after upgrading my flutter. I was connected to the internet but my clock was not on correct time. After I have corrected the time on my pc, the error was solved.