# Flutter got No issues found but still can not get the packages after create project

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, flutter

Flutter got No issues found but still can not get the packages after create project with the "Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org." error

I tried these:

[Flutter app behind corporate firewall throws TLS error during packages get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883151/flutter-app-behind-corporate-firewall-throws-tls-error-during-packages-get?rq=1)

[Network Connection Proxies in Dart Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021315/network-connection-proxies-in-dart-editor)

**flutter -v doctor -v**

```
[  +15 ms] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +722 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +2 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +612 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[ +741 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +659 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 8661d8aecd626f7f57ccbcb735553edc05a2e713
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[ +675 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 7 weeks ago
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[ +672 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] v1.2.1-0-g8661d8aec
[+3410 ms] java -version
[ +174 ms] [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.847], locale tr-TR)
[   +3 ms]     • Flutter version 1.2.1 at Q:\Developer\flutter
[   +1 ms]     • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (7 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
[        ]     • Engine revision 3757390fa4
[        ]     • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
\[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\Kafeduran.NTD_EBI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices -l
[ +458 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\Kafeduran.NTD_EBI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices -l
[   +1 ms] List of devices attached
           ad78615b               device product:gemini model:MI_5 device:gemini transport_id:1
[  +13 ms] C:\Users\Kafeduran.NTD_EBI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb -s ad78615b shell getprop           |[ +551 ms] executing: C:\Users\Kafeduran.NTD_EBI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses
[  +53 ms] ro.hardware = qcom                                                                                          [+56173 ms] [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[   +1 ms]     • Android SDK at C:\Users\Kafeduran.NTD_EBI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
[   +1 ms]     • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
[        ]     • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
[        ]     • Java binary at: Q:\Developer\android-studio\jre\bin\java
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
[        ]     • All Android licenses accepted.
[   +1 ms] [√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[        ]     • Android Studio at Q:\Developer\android-studio
[        ]     • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
[        ]     • Dart plugin version 182.5215
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
[        ] [√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
[        ]     • IntelliJ at Q:\Developer\editors
[        ]     • Flutter plugin version 34.0.4
[        ]     • Dart plugin version 191.6183.87
[   +1 ms] [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.32.3)
[        ]     • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
[        ]     • Flutter extension version 2.25.0
[        ] [√] Proxy Configuration
[        ]     • HTTP_PROXY is set
[        ]     • NO_PROXY is localhost,127.0.0.1
[        ]     • NO_PROXY contains 127.0.0.1
[        ]     • NO_PROXY contains localhost
[        ] [√] Connected device (1 available)
[        ]     • MI 5 • ad78615b • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
[        ] • No issues found!
[   +7 ms] "flutter doctor" took 60.205ms.
[        ] "flutter doctor" took 60.205ms.
```

**flutter -v create -v rad**

```
[  +18 ms] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +703 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +2 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +626 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[ +617 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[   +1 ms] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +647 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 8661d8aecd626f7f57ccbcb735553edc05a2e713
[        ] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[ +646 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 7 weeks ago
[   +1 ms] executing: [Q:\Developer\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[ +668 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] v1.2.1-0-g8661d8aec
[+1033 ms] Creating project rad...
[  +95 ms]   rad\.gitignore (created)
[  +12 ms]   rad\.idea\libraries\Dart_SDK.xml (created)
[  +11 ms]   rad\.idea\libraries\Flutter_for_Android.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\.idea\libraries\KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\.idea\modules.xml (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\.idea\runConfigurations\main_dart.xml (created)
[   +5 ms]   rad\.idea\workspace.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\.metadata (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\android\app\build.gradle (created)
[   +8 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\rad\MainActivity.java (created)
[  +19 ms]   rad\android\build.gradle (created)
[   +7 ms]   rad\android\rad_android.iml (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +7 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml (created)
[  +11 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[  +10 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +8 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[  +10 ms]   rad\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
[   +8 ms]   rad\android\gradle.properties (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\android\settings.gradle (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.h (created)
[   +7 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.m (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\main.m (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj (created)
[  +15 ms]   rad\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (created)
[  +10 ms]   rad\ios\Flutter\AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
[   +8 ms]   rad\ios\Flutter\Debug.xcconfig (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Flutter\Release.xcconfig (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
[   +7 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\Contents.json (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
[   +3 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\README.md (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\Main.storyboard (created)
[   +4 ms]   rad\ios\Runner\Info.plist (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
[   +6 ms]   rad\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (existing - skipped)
[   +2 ms]   rad\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
[  +10 ms]   rad\lib\main.dart (created)
[   +8 ms]   rad\rad.iml (created)
[  +12 ms]   rad\pubspec.yaml (created)
[  +10 ms]   rad\README.md (created)
[   +9 ms]   rad\test\widget_test.dart (created)
[ +103 ms] Running "flutter packages get" in rad...
[   +5 ms] Using Q:\Developer\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +2 ms] executing: [Q:\workspace\projects\rad\] Q:\Developer\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat
--verbosity=warning --verbose get --no-precompile
[+66695 ms] Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
[  +27 ms] pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
[+1019 ms] Using Q:\Developer\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +2 ms] executing: [Q:\workspace\projects\rad\] Q:\Developer\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat
--verbosity=warning --verbose get --no-precompile
[+68239 ms] Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
[  +29 ms] pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
[+2012 ms] Using Q:\Developer\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +2 ms] executing: [Q:\workspace\projects\rad\] Q:\Developer\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat
--verbosity=warning --verbose get --no-precompile
[+66594 ms] Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
[  +28 ms] pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
[+4008 ms] Using Q:\Developer\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +3 ms] executing: [Q:\workspace\projects\rad\]
```

Getting this error:
"Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org."

It can not get packages. Do you have any idea what can I try to get rid of?

Comment: There is an issue on github about this, maybe it will help you https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15014

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that your Flutter project is unable to download packages. You should try uninstalling and reinstalling Flutter again and see if it works, similar to what has been suggested on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69329#issuecomment-720282176). It's possible that there's some components that you're using that were corrupted after an upgrade.